# passing java method as an argument or create a method local variable

Tags: java

Please look at option-1 and option-2 below.

I have some experienced people telling me that option-1 is the best and recommended way to go as it improves readability.  Also, helps in knowing variable value during debug session.

However, option-2 removes the following possibilities:

- avoids unnecessary local variable creation and an additional line of code
- accidental altering of object state as someone can call t.someMethod(..) to alter state of object `t`
- accidental assignment of `t` to another instance of Entity (of course this can be avoided using final key word on variable t declaration).

Please let me know what the widely accepted way out of this.

---

#### option-1:

```
public void method()
{
   Entity t = method1();
   method2(t);
}
```

---

#### option-2:

```
public void method()
{
   method2(method1());
}
```

Comment: Should be a codereview question

Comment: Depends on the context, but most of the times I prefer option 1. If methods are poorly named, you can't directly tell which type of argument you're passing on and thereby forcing each developer to look up the return value of that method.

Comment: Based on "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live." I would vote for option 1. Readability is important and JIT probably will optimize this code to one from option 2.

Comment: Uncle Bob, or Robert Cecil Martin, the author of "Clean Code" does a much better job of describing why option 2 is preferred; but his description would include that you pick much better method names.  `setCssColorToBlue(getTitleElement())` is far more readable than `setCssColorToBlue(entity)` with `entity` being captured some 10 lines above the method.